# Pub/Sub to Text Files on Cloud Storage template at DataFlow FileNotFoundException error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to Dataflow. I am sending JSON data to pub/sub using a python script. I am using the "Pub/Sub to Text Files on Cloud Storage" template that I created in Dataflow.
When I want to write to Cloud Storage, it writes to the folder named .temp-beam instead of the bucket I specified as the output path. I know this is a fault-tolerant.
In the dataflow logs, I get the following error:

`Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: gs://mybucket/data/.temp-beam/d96626fc549ca4e3-77c2`

Example data in Pub/Sub:

`{"productFullName": "watch", "productBrand": "Rolex", "productPrice": "1089.00", "productRating": "100", "productRatingCount": "15", "productDealer": "WatchCenter", "dealerRating": "100"}`

I tried everything on the permission side.
I've verified from .temp-beam that my data is coming in correctly.
Tried txt and json as suffix.
Bucket path was made as desired. ( gs://bucket/data/ )

DataFlow SDK Version: Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.36.0

Comment: Just to confirm, `gs://mybucket/data/.temp-beam` exists and has the correct permissions? What stage is this error happening in? Are the files getting written then deleted, or failing to get written at all?

Comment: @robertwb Thank you for your interest. Dataflow creates the gs://mybucket/data/.temp-beam folder and writes the data there correctly. But this path is not where I specified as output path when creating dataflow. Dataflow always gets the same error while writing data to storage. The file that I specified as a prefix does not occur in the folder I want me to. The bucket I want to use has the necessary permissions. (Example: DataFlow Admin, Cloud Dataflow Service Agent)